# Is it possible to reduce the number of arguments of \frac?

Tags: math-mode

The number of arguments of the command `\frac` is two. Is it possible to make it only one?

For instance, I would like to make `$\frac{a}{b}$` as, say `$\quot{a,b}$`.

Comment: And how do you want to write `\frac{1,200}{3.147}`? Why do you want to change the syntax of this?

Comment: When long expressions are put in the arguments of '\frac', so many '{' and '}' enter so that the error probability increases.

Comment: Does your editor have auto closing delimiters?

Comment: No. I turned it off. It is annoying. For now I do not have a direct example at hand.

Comment: It is possible, but it will lead to confusion, especially when a friend or coworker or copy editor is reviewing your source code. Braces (or groups in general) are a really useful thing. Your text editor can help you in making it more pleasing to the eye.

Comment: That is some issue worthy of further thoughts. But, yes, please show it :)

Comment: I suppose you could write `\frac a b` instead of `\frac{a}{b}`. However, the loss in terms of code readability must exceed any benefits that may arise from typing four fewer curly braces.

Comment: I guess that loss of readability is subjective. I always preferred to write `\frac12` instead of `\frac{1}{2}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- i have always been sorry that latex abolished the "delimited" control sequence.  there are some applications (not necessarily math texts) in which they are *much* clearer than braces.  (said by one who once spent more than 4 hours looking for one missing brace in the input of a membership directory.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton You had the shortwire years back when i wasn't even born yet, and still have it today. I can't do anything. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not do this but

```
\newcommand\quot[1]{\xquot#1\relax}
\def\xquot#1,#2\relax{\frac{#1}{#2}}
```

does what you ask.

Comment: Thank you. I believe { } is around \quot?

Comment: @Chou you mean `\newcommand{\quot}`  ? You may do that if you wish, it's optional.

Comment: Yes. Just found that my editor does not eat it without the big brackets :) But it works perfectly when the big brackets enter.

Comment: `$\quot{x^2, d_2}$` as you ask! ;-)

Comment: Hey thank you. I see. I was saying that my editor does not read the original answer but read it when I add big brackets around \quot.

Comment: @Chou sorry I can not guess what you mean. The definition above implements the syntax that you requested.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you very much. (I mean my editor does not read your answer as the answer presently is. But the editor reads your answer when it becomes \newcommand{quot}[1]...)

Comment: @Chou - If you don't tell us which editor you use, it's not possible to anticipate any editor-related programming quirks.

Comment: @Mico (also if that editor isn't emacs I wouldn't be able to help:-)

Comment: @Chou An editor doesn't need to understand tex syntax at all, so long as it is correct latex syntax it just needs  to pass it to tex to be interpreted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle While that's true, it's majorly annoying if syntax highlighting skrews up and half of your document is mathematics-colored or something. :/ Not that the (La)TeX can (or should have to) do anything about that...

Comment: Things like `\quot{1,2\relax+2}` may fail, I guess